# How to merge lists to obtain list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I want to merge three lists in a specific way.
Consider the lists:

```
a = [ a1 , a2 , a3 , a4 ]
b = [ b1 , b2 , b3 , b4 ]
c = [ c1 , c2 , c3 , c4 ]
```

And finally, I want to obtain a list of lists:

```
res = [[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]....[a4,b4,c4]]
```

I'm a newbie in Python. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps the built-in function [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) will be useful to you.

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: What are those `a1`, `a2`, etc.? Do you really have 12 variables with those names lying around? Or did you want the strings `'a1', 'a2', …`?

Answer (score 7):

You can try [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

Python 2.x:

```
>>> a = [ 'a1' , 'a2' , 'a3' , 'a4' ]
>>> b = [ 'b1' , 'b2' , 'b3' , 'b4' ]
>>> c = [ 'c1' , 'c2' , 'c3' , 'c4' ]
>>>
>>> map(list, zip(a,b,c))
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'], ['a4', 'b4', 'c4']]
```

Python 3.x:

```
>>> a = [ 'a1' , 'a2' , 'a3' , 'a4' ]
>>> b = [ 'b1' , 'b2' , 'b3' , 'b4' ]
>>> c = [ 'c1' , 'c2' , 'c3' , 'c4' ]
>>> 
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(a,b,c)]
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'], ['a4', 'b4', 'c4']]
```

The 3.x version also works as expected in 2.x, but I always like to use `map` where I easily can. The reason the 2.x version doesn't work as expected in 3.x is because `zip()` and `map()` were both changed to return iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`x = zip(listA, listB, listC)`

Python is beautiful like that.  Now this will give you tuples, not lists within your list.  Converting from tuple to list requires a `y = list(x)` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,8]

print zip(*[a,b,c])

[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 8)]
```

Comment: What is with the `*[a, b, c]`... Just type it out normally? :P

Comment: zip(*[a, b, c]) is the same as zip(a, b, c).

Comment: @Guetti I am aware of that - let me rephrase - why would you suggest creating a list and unpacking it over `zip(a, b, c)`?

Comment: If you really want to use asterisks, wouldn't `(lambda *x: zip(*x))(*[a,b,c])` be more fun?

Comment: @abarnert At that stage of anti-golf - we should start trying to throw some recursion in there... that's even more fun

Comment: @JonClements: You're right, how could I have forgotten?! But we only have an expression, not an assignment, which means we can only use `lambda`, which means we have no name to recurse on, which means we need a higher-order function to help us… but really, what could be more simple and fundamental than using a fixed-point combinator? I'll leave the obvious implementation as an exercise for the reader.